# Tell screen window to run the previous command

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
    nnoremap <F1> :!screen -S foo -p run -X stuff '!!^M'
```

However, when click F1, I get the error: No previous command.

What I want is to tell the 'run' window in screen session named 'foo' to run whatever I ran just before.

Comment: I do not see a reason for this behavior, but you have two errors here: `<F1>` preceded by `:!ls` will run command `:!screen -S foo -p run -X stuff 'lsls` (without trailing `'`!): 1. two bangs produce two previous commands and 2. `^M` (in case it is raw `<CR>` produced by `<C-v><CR>`) executes `:!` command. You should use `'!<C-v><CR>'<CR>`.

Comment: How exactly did you run whatever you ran just before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant `!!` to be executed by bash (hence “run whatever I ran before *in that screen instance*”) then you have to escape it:

```
nnoremap <F1> :!screen -S foo -p run -X stuff $'\!\!\n'<CR>
```

or use `system()`:

```
nnoremap <F1> :call system('screen -S foo -p run -X stuff $''!!\n''')<CR>
```

. Because `!` in any bang thingie means “place here whatever I ran before *in vim using other bang thingie*”

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that ! in vim is also previous command. Using system() also has a nice benefit of not forcing me to hit an extra Enter.

Comment: @DatChu First variant can be modified in order not to force you to hit Enter: use `:silent !…` and `<C-l>` after `<CR>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try saving the history file using a trick like this: http://www.cuberick.com/2008/11/update-bash-history-in-realtime.html

Then, once you have the history, run screen with the command as a parameter - notice that `screen dmesg` will run the command and terminate. If you don't want it to terminate, you'd do `screen bash -c "dmesg ; bash"` (or whatever shell you run). So, once you know the trick, the point is to put `tail -n1 .bash_history` instead of dmesg.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I later noticed the "vim" caption. It kind of works for me this way:

```
:nnoremap <F1> :!screen bash -c " '!!'"
```

Comment: Damn, sorry, it's not about vim.